# updating where %programfiles% points to

Tags: windows-7

`%ProgramFiles%` somehow got updated to point to `E:\Program Files`. I'd like to update it to point to `C:\Program Files\` instead.

If I right click on Computer and click on "Properties" -> Advanced system settings -> "Environment Variables..." I don't see `%ProgramFiles%` as a system variable in the list of system variables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Where is %ProgramFiles% defined?

- Run `regedt32`
- Find the following key:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
- You will see a String Value `ProgramFilesDir`.

  [image]
- Right click `ProgramFilesDir` and select "Modify".
- Change the value to `C:\Program Files` and click "OK".

  Note: There should **not** be a trailing `\`

  [image]